# Simple Event Binding (Jquery & Rails)

Tags: jquery

I have a container that exists in my DOM .customers-container. Within that container, I am adding new "tr"s through ajax calls.

How can I apply event binding to those dynamically created elements. I am using below, but it's not working on the new elements:

```
 $('.customers-container').find('.glyphicon-remove').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').hide();
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate the event from `.customers-container` to `.glyphicon-remove`:

```
$('.customers-container').on('click', '.glyphicon-remove', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
});
```

Note that the `on` method parameters have changed, now the first parameter `click` is the event name, the second parameter `.glyphicon-remove` are the elements that will receive the event binding from the `.customers-container` delegator, and the third function is the function to execute when the event fires.

Comment: exactly what I needed!